# "Declaration Not allowed here" and "Constant Expression" Error in C

Tags: c

I used Microsoft Visual Studio to write a C code in C++ project and It's working fine there when I convert the file extension from my.cpp to my.c and tried to run in via TurboC++ 3.0 then it gives me number of errors like "Constant Expression Required" and "Declaration is not allowed here".
I tried to run my code online compiler but its not giving me these error there.

Can anyone help me with this ?

I hope it's due to C99 mode but not confirmed.
TurboC++ 3.0 Supports C99 or not ?

Note: I can't share my code directly here due to project research work , If anyone want to have a look at my code I can send you via private message , Sorty for that

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B: "Turbo C++ 3.0 was released in 1991..."

Comment: This site doesn't have private messaging. It's a public support forum. You'll need to post some sort of code for us to look at. If you can't post your actual code, post something similar that exhibits the same problem.

Comment: You changed the file extension from `.cpp` to `.c`. Is the code C or C++?

Comment: dude, there are lots of changes in cpp , very basic is variable declaration. u neeed to post your piece of code so we can predict what the problem is.

Comment: one more thing I have noticed I am getting this "Constant Expression required" error with array declared variables only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error: `Declaration Not allowed here` is due to the mixed type declaration of variables and the error: `Constant Expression required` is because of the variable length arrays.
Mixed type variables and variable length arrays are are allowed in C99 and latter. Neither MSVC nor Turbo C++ supports C99.

> I tried to run my code online compiler but its not giving me these error there.

This is because almost all new (and online) C compilers support C99.

Comment: Thanks, any hints on how to solve this Constant Expression error , I read some topics on internet about memory allocation while defining array but they were not helpful.

and any suggestion which compiler should I install on my PC which supports C99?

Comment: Change `const int o=2000; ` to `#define o 2000`, but it will need a bigger stack to work for arrays.